# Iterate over 2 Arraylists checking equal values of different types before giving result?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, model-view-controller, arraylist

I'm not fully sure how to phrase this but I am doing an assignment using Java swing MVC for a movie Catalogue. I have JTextfields and when the user adds a movie with the movie details, before saving the movie it has to check if the genre, cast etc already exist. If they do then it is added ok. If they do not exist then for example, the genre needs to be added to the genre class and then used to add the movie.

When the genres are added as string, it is converted to an arraylist.  Then another arraylist of all the existing genres is added. There are 2 for loops and then an if/else to check if true or not:

```
String genres = addNewItem1.getGenretextfield().getText();
        String[] items = genres.split(",");
        List <String> genreStringArray = Arrays.asList(items);//temp
        ArrayList<genres> genArray  = new ArrayList<genres>();//Empty


    int nextGid = model.getGenres().size()+1; 
                
        for(genres g: model.getGenres()){ 
             for(String s: genreStringArray) {
             if(g.getGenre().contentEquals(s)) { 
                 genArray.add(g);                
             }  
                System.out.print("No");
             } 
         }

         shows.setGenre(genArray);
```

If the genre already exist, the genres get added to'genArray'.  The issue is with if they do not exist.  As it is inside 2 for loops in the else section I have a sys.out to test, it will print several times. I only want that genre that don't exists already to add to another arraylist. I have tried several different variations of the for loops and if/else but I just get the same result. As the ArrayLists are off two different types I have to use contentEquals rather than ==.  I have tried the .remove() method also but because they are different types it doesn't not allow it.

```
  Existing Genres(Animation, Comedy, Thriller, Drama)//List of existing genres
  GenreStringArray(Musical,Comedy)//User added genre list
  GenArray(Comedy)//GenArray gets genres that do exist
  genreStringArray(Musical)//This array keeps the non existent genres that were added
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You could use an implementation of [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to avoid duplication as long as the objects you put in the `Set` follow the contracts of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods

Comment: I think editable combo box can help.